# How to keep return value while processing a command's output?

Tags: bash, grep, tee

In Bash environment, I have a command, and I want to detect if it fails.

However it is not failing gracefully:

```
# ./program
do stuff1
do stuff2
    error!
do stuff3
# echo $?
0
```

When it runs without errors (successful run), it returns with `0`. When it runs into an error, it can either

- return with `1`, easily detectable
- return with `0`, but during run it prints some error messages

I want to use this `program` in a script with these goals:

- I need the output to be printing to stdout normally (not at once after it finished!)
- I need to catch the output's return value by `$?` or similar
- I need to `grep` for "error" string in the output and set a variable in case of presence

Then I can evaluate by checking the return value and the "error" output.

However, if I add `tee`, it will ruin the return value.

I have tried `$PIPESTATUS[0]` and `$PIPESTATUS[1]`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
program | tee >(grep -i error)
```

Even if there is no error, $PIPESTATUS[1] always returns 0 (true), because the `tee` command was successful.

So what is the way to do this in bash?

Comment: `yourprogram_output=$(yourprogram); yourprogram_rc=$?` -- as lang as you don't do something else that messes it up like using `local`/`export`/`declare`/etc on the same line, assignments don't modify exit status.

Comment: And, uhh, why are you checking `PIPESTATUS[1]` when you want to know about the success of the program whose exit status is in `PIPESTATUS[0]`?

Comment: (Also, note that `$PIPESTATUS[0]` _is not_ `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`; the curly braces aren't optional when you're trying to do an array dereference).

Comment: `yourprogram_output=$(yourprogram); yourprogram_rc=$?` violates my first requirement: "I need the output to be printing to stdout normally (not at once after it finished!)"

Comment: `${PIPESTATUS[1]}`: I wanted to get the returncode of the `grep` in `tee`.

Comment: In `program | tee >(grep -i error)`, only `program` and `tee` are part of the pipe; `grep` is not, so it's not _expected_ to be anywhere in `PIPESTATUS`.

Comment: Your ability to collect exit status from a process substitution depends on the specific version of bash in use; if you don't have something fairly recent (I want to say 4.3?), it isn't possible.

Comment: I can live without process substitution if all my above goals and expectations can be fulfilled somehow else without using any files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[0-3].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.3+ required" >2; exit 1;;
esac

exec {stdout_fd}>&1
if "$@" | tee "/dev/fd/$stdout_fd" | grep -i error >/dev/null; then
  echo "Errors occurred (detected on stdout)" >&2
elif (( ${PIPESTATUS[0]} )); then
  echo "Errors detected (via exit status)" >&2
else
  echo "No errors occurred" >&2
fi
```

Tested as follows:

```
$ myfunc() { echo "This is an ERROR"; return 0; }; export -f myfunc
$ ./test-err myfunc
This is an ERROR
Errors occurred (detected on stdout)
```

```
$ myfunc() { echo "Everything is not so fine"; return 1; }; export -f myfunc
$ ./test-err myfunc
Everything is not so fine
Errors detected (via exit status)
```

```
$ myfunc() { echo "Everything is fine"; }; export -f myfunc
$ ./test-err myfunc
Everything is fine
No errors occurred
```

Comment: What is `exec {stdout_fd}>&1` actually doing?

Comment: It makes `stdout_fd` contain an automatically-allocated file descriptor number where the FD in question is a copy of your program's original stdout.

Comment: If you needed compatibility with older versions of bash you could hardcode a number -- `exec 10>&1`, for example, then use `tee /dev/fd/10` later.

Comment: I see, thanks. Operations on these `fds` are not involving any file operations? I'm on a flash storage and I'd avoid unnecessary writings onto it.

Comment: So, this could also be `exec {stdout_fd_for_my_own_purposes}>&1` ?

Comment: Yes, `exec {any_variable_name}>&1` will put the new FD in `any_variable_name`. And yes, `/dev/fd` does not involve disk; the details depend on your operating system, but pretty much anywhere it's supported it's just synthesized in-memory on access.

Comment: (on Linux, f/e, `/dev/fd` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`, and all of `/proc` is in-memory)